WinForms Invalidate() problems, redrawing as fast as possible
I want to redraw my WinForm as fast as possible, but still play nice and keep the controls in the form working. I avoid using Update() and Refresh() since those methods force a redraw of the form. I just want it to be redrawn at the next suitable time. So I call Invalidate() at the end of my OnPaint() method, which should just signal that the form should be repainted whenever there is time for it. The refresh rate is very good, but the ComboBox is not drawn until I click it or move the window. Which makes me feel that this is not the correct way to request redraws as fast as possible:
public class TimeForm : Form
{
  private readonly ComboBox _mode = new ComboBox();
  private readonly Font _font = new Font("Verdana", 20, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

  public TimeForm()
  {
    SuspendLayout();
    _mode.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    _mode.Size = new Size(280, 23);
    _mode.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    _mode.Items.Add("Standard");
    _mode.SelectedIndex = 0;

    ClientSize = new Size(300, 100);
    Controls.Add(_mode);
    ResumeLayout(false);
  }

  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    DoubleBuffered = true;
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), _font, Brushes.Black, 10, 50);
    Invalidate();
  }
}


If I move the call to Invalidate() to another thread running in the background, things are the same. But if I add a Thread.Yield() to play nice, the ComboBox is drawn.
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
  while(!IsDisposed)
  {
    Invalidate();
    Thread.Yield();
  }
});


However, this example is a bit less complex than my real program so I added a Thread.Sleep(10) in my OnPaint method to simulate a more complex drawing. Then I'm back to the ComboBox not being drawn.
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), _font, Brushes.Black, 10, 50);
    Thread.Sleep(10);
  }

I really don't want to adjust the delay in the background thread depending on the execution time of the OnPaint method.
What is the proper way to kindly request a redraw as quickly as possible, without causing problem for the rest of the form?

Why as fast as possible? If you want smooth animations you can't just redraw the form. Sleeping for 10ms won't give you 100 FPS either. It will be far less and stutter. For starters, the Windows timer resolution is 16ms - it's meant for thread scheduling, NOT animation. Second, Thread.Sleep evicts the thread from the CPU. The thread now has to wait to be rescheduled. If you want simple animation of controls WPF is a far better option, with direct animation support

Use a timer with interval being set to 1.

Using Invalidate inside OnPaint isn't helping either. OnPain is called in response to the Windows WM_PAINT event. One reason that message is called is ... Invalidate. You can invalidate only the region you want to repaint eg in a timer, so you only have to redraw that region. Thread.Sleep prevents redrawing of the form entirely, so it's a really bad idea. PS: A Label controls with a changing text at a specific location would work better than the current code.

By default, timers will give you 60hz, and this is usually sufficient, there is no point rendering more frames than the display can show. There are various APIs for time sensitive tasks, like audio and video. "Multimedia Class Scheduler Service" might be of interest. But it is difficult to provide help without understanding the actual problem you are trying to solve. And things like Thread.Sleep is directly counter productive to a well functioning UI.

Instead of painting everything in OnPaint check PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle to see if you need to paint that string or not. A Label control already takes care of all this. Its own OnPaint is only called when the Label itself needs to be repainted

Clearly you're on the wrong track.  Simply drop a Timer on the form and set its Interval to 10.  In its Tick event call Invalidate().  Do prefer a Label to prevent having to repaint the entire form.

If you have complex drawing tasks, you can use double buffering, draw in another buffered Graphics context and display the completed context in the end. At this point though it may be better to start looking at WPF or dedicated animation libraries.

The Thread.Sleep() was just a simple way to illustrate that the problem reappears when the OnPaint method is more time consuming. I thought that using a Timer with Interval = 1 ms might cause the same problems if the OnPaint method is more time consuming than that, but it seems to work fine. I guess the Tick event is delayed until OnPaint have finished executing. But on the other hand, I can't really understand why calling Invalidate() from the end of OnPaint causes problem when calling it from the Tick event does not...

Because when you invalidate the window on each WM_PAINT, your Form is busy just doing that. You should probably talk about your real use case. If you have set the Timer's interval to 1ms, that's not the actual interval at which the Timer ticks. As mentioned, that's way beyond its capability, and even if the Timer has a minimum interval of ~15ms, in a UI that's, theoretically, the lowest possible, but not actually what you get anyway (that Timer uses the WM_TIMER message mode, which is low priority). It's not clear why you would update the UI at a rate that no human eye can appreciate

you can always call update() on controls in stead of on the entire form. But I would keep away from putting code inside OnPaint. But when you need Update() on a control or form, that sounds to me like you have another problem, you should actually never have to call that
